# Time input and display

Tags: java

I am trying to make the program take input and display it in the format I have specified in displayTime method. Instead of ask the user to input the value it skips straight to displayTime method and assigns value to 00;00;00. Can someone help me and let me know what needs changing so it takes the input first then displays?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Time {
 Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
 private int hour = 0;
 private int minute = 0;
 private int second = 0;

 public void getHour(int h) {
 h = hour;
 System.out.println("Enter Hour:");
 h = input.nextInt();

 }
 public void getMinute(int m) {
     m = minute;
     System.out.println("Enter Minute:");
     m = input.nextInt();
 }
 public void getSecond(int s) {
     s = second;
     System.out.println("Enter Second:");
     s = input.nextInt();
 }

 public String displayTime() {
 return String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", hour, minute, second);
}
}
public class Test {

public static void main (String args[]) {
Time TimeObject = new Time();
System.out.println(TimeObject.displayTime());
}   
}
```

Comment: Not a good Question for Stack Overflow. You could have looked at any of the hundreds of existing Questions about Scanner and compared your code. Then you world have either (a) solved your problem or (b) narrowed it down to a very specific issue to raise here.

Answer (score 1):

Many things are wrong in your example. First of all, variable names start in lowercase in Java by convention, second, your method  `getHour(int h)` is expecting an hour to be passed, but also requesting it from the keyboard. Doesn't make sense to me.

Saying that, I'd rather do something like:

```
public class Time {

Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
private int hours = 0;
private int minutes = 0;
private int seconds = 0;

private int getHours() {
    System.out.println("Hours:");
    int hour = input.nextInt();
    if (hour < 0 || hour >= 24) {
        System.out.println("Wrong input. Hours must be between 0 and 23.Try again...");
        return getHours();
    }
    return hour;
}

private int getMinutes() {
    System.out.println("Minutes:");
    int minute = input.nextInt();
    if (minute < 0 || minute >= 60) {
        System.out.println("Wrong input. Minutes must be between 0 and 59. Try again...");
        return getMinutes();
    }
    return minute;
}

private int getSeconds() {
    System.out.println("Seconds:");
    int second = input.nextInt();
    if (second < 0 || second >= 60) {
        System.out.println("Wrong input. Seconds must be between 0 and 59. Try again...");
        return getSeconds();
    }
    return second;
}

public void getTime() {
    hours = getHours();
    minutes = getMinutes();
    seconds = getSeconds();
}

public String displayTime() {
    return String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", hours, minutes, seconds);
}
}
```

And your main:

```
public class Test {

public static void main(String args[]) {
    Time time = new Time();
    time.getTime();
    System.out.println(time.displayTime());

}

}
```

It will recursively ask for the value until it gets entered in the proper range.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
class Time {
private int hour = 0;
private int minute = 0;
private int second = 0;

public void getHour(int h) {
    hour = h;
}
public void getMinute(int m) {
    minute = m;
}

public void getSecond(int s) {
    second = s;
}
public String displayTime() {
    return String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", hour, minute, second);
}
}
public class Test{
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int h, m, s;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter Hour:");
    h = input.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter Minute:");
    m = input.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter Second:");
    s = input.nextInt();
    Time TimeObject = new Time();
    TimeObject.getHour(h);
    TimeObject.getMinute(m);
    TimeObject.getSecond(s);
    System.out.println(TimeObject.displayTime());
}
}
```

Comment: Thank you, i guess i should take the input in the main class ?

Comment: You have not call getHour(),getMinute(),getSecond() inside main(). That's why code inside these methods are not running

Answer (score 0):

As far as the actual handling of the time you would like to create and format, why don't you use Java's Calendar API?

Have a look at this:

https://www.mkyong.com/java/java-date-and-calendar-examples/